# Ошибка redis

Tags: node-redis, redis

```
error event - 127.0.0.1:6379 - Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED
    at RedisClient.on_error (/home/www/site.com/node_modules/redis/index.js:189:24)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/www/site.com/node_modules/redis/index.js:95:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:441:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

При этом redis установлен и запущен командой redis-server

```
[8857] 29 Nov 18:14:31.466 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf [8857] 29 Nov 18:14:31.467 * Max number of open files set to 10032 [8857] 29 Nov 18:14:31.468 # Server started, Redis version 2.8.0 [8857] 29 Nov 18:14:31.468 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
```

Comment: а почему вы не задали конфигурационный файл для редис?

Comment: Он по умолчанию. Помогло следующее apt-get -f install и после команда sudo apt-get install redis-server

Comment: Разве нельзя оставить настройки по умолчанию? насколько это критично?

Comment: не то чтобы очень критично, но лично я предпочитаю быть уверенным во всех конфигах, а не надеяться на дефолт

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, у вас Redis запущен без TCP, в конфигах указан порт 0. Чтобы работал с TCP, должен быть указан порт, обычно 6379. Но лучше работать через unix-сокет - так быстрее.